# R mschart turn off line smoothing

Tags: r, mschart, officer

I'm using mschart version 0.2.6 to draw line charts in R for powerpoint.  I get smoothed lines by default but don't want that.  How do I turn it off?

I found the following feature request on github but it's closed and I'm not sure how it was resolved:
https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/issues/25

Here is a working example:

```
library(officer)
library(mschart)

dat<-data.frame(Year=c(rep("2010",3), rep("2011",3), rep("2012",3)),
            Fruit=c(rep(c("Apples","Oranges","Pears"),3)),
            Count = c(332,229,168,
                      223,189,225,
                      321,378,261), stringsAsFactors=F)

line_chart <- ms_linechart(data = dat, x = "Year",y = "Count", group="Fruit")

doc <- read_pptx()
doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
doc <- ph_with(x = doc, value = c("Fruit"),
             location = ph_location_type(type = "title") )
doc <- ph_with(doc, line_chart, location = ph_location_type(type="body"))
fileout <- "./Test.pptx" 
print(doc, target = fileout)
```

Here is what it produces.  Notice the Smoothed Line option checked in lower left:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe (or wrap) the `ms_linechart` object into a `chart_data_smooth()` function with `values` set to 0.

```
library(officer)
library(mschart)
library(tidyverse)

line_chart <- ms_linechart(data = dat, x = "Year",y = "Count", group="Fruit") %>% 
              chart_data_smooth(values = 0) # Here is the code that sets lines to straight.

doc <- read_pptx()
doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
doc <- ph_with(x = doc, value = c("Fruit"),
               location = ph_location_type(type = "title") )
doc <- ph_with(doc, line_chart, location = ph_location_type(type="body"))
fileout <- "./Test2.pptx" 
print(doc, target = fileout)
```

[image]