# How to turn off smoothing/blurring when plotting a matrix as an cimg object

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot this checker pattern:

```
checker_pattern <- rbind(c(1/3, 2/3),
                         c(2/3, 1/3))
plot(imager::as.cimg(checker_pattern))
```

According to this site http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2019/01/image-dithering-in-r/, we should get the following outcome, which I also desire:

[image]

However, I get this outcome running the exact same code:

[image]

**Why do R seem to blur or smooth out the colors in the plot? How do I turn off this blurring?**

A similar question ([R mschart turn off line smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132950/r-mschart-turn-off-line-smoothing)) mentions scaling. I do not know if that gives us a clue in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Set the `interpolate` argument to `FALSE` (and furthermore, `rescale` to `FALSE`):

```r
plot(imager::as.cimg(checker_pattern), interpolate = FALSE, rescale = FALSE)
```

[image]

**Rationale**

This has nothing to do with R, and everything to do with the `imager` package (or rather, the `cimg` object). You are creating an object of the class `cimg`, and then provoke `plot.cimg`. That function has an `interpolate` argument, which defaults to `TRUE`. This is then fed into the `as.raster` function downstream, which applies interpolation. By setting `interpolate = FALSE` you remove this effect.

Following the same procedure, I found that the `plot.cimg` also has a `rescale` argument, which defaults to `TRUE`. Setting it to `FALSE` correctly displays the colors.

You can find more information about this function by typing `?plot.cimg`.